# configure: error: zlib development files not found

Tags: r

I'm trying to install RSEM software. To compile RSEM, I ran "make", then I got the following error:

```
[configure: error: zlib development files not found
Samtools uses compression routines from the zlib library <http://zlib.net>.
Building samtools requires zlib development files to be installed on the build
machine; you may need to ensure a package such as zlib1g-dev (on Debian or
Ubuntu Linux) or zlib-devel (on RPM-based Linux distributions) is installed.]
```

Actually, I already installed zlib-devel on my server (Red hat EL 7.4). 
[Package zlib-devel-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version]

Can anyone help me figure it out? 
Thanks

Comment: r u installing it as sudo?

Comment: I did not use sudo, I used "yum install zlib-devel" to install. I tried to use sudo, but it did not work. [Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, package_upload, product-id, search-
              : disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-rpms                                       | 2.0 kB     00:00     
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.2-rpms                   | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Package zlib-devel-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager]

Comment: I think u need sudo to install zlib-devel so that all users can use it

Comment: I tried to use sudo, but it didn't work too. anyway, thanks for your suggestions.